# Read an array of 32bit ints from a binary format file?

Tags: c#

OK so I have converted a file into a binary format using BinaryWriter. The format is:

number of ints, followed by the ints.

So the code will be something like:

```
readLineOfNumbers() {
    count = read();
    int[] a = read(count ints);
    return a;
}
```

Do I use a BinaryReader? The closest thing I can see there is to read everything into a byte[], but then how do I make that an int array? This all has to be done very efficiently as well. I need buffering and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything within `BinaryReader` which will read an array of integers, I'm afraid. If you read into a byte array you could then use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy those bytes into an `int[]`, which is probably the fastest form of conversion - although it relies on the endianness of your processor being appropriate for your data.

Have you *tried* just looping round, calling `BinaryReader.ReadInt32()` as many times as you need to, and letting the file system do the buffering? You could always add a `BufferedStream` with a large buffer into the mix if you thought that would help.

Answer (score 2):

If you use BinaryWriter to create file it makes sense to read it using BinaryReader

Something like:

```
private static int[] ReadArray(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        int count = reader.ReadInt32();
        int[] data = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            data[i] = reader.ReadInt32();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] original = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, copy;
byte[] bytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
    {
        writer.Write(original.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
            writer.Write(original[i]);
    }
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ms))
{
    int len = reader.ReadInt32();
    copy = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = reader.ReadInt32();
    }
}
```

Although personally I'd just read from the stream w/o `BinaryReader`.

Actually, *strictly* speaking, if it was me I would use my [own serializer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), and just:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1, Options = MemberSerializationOptions.Packed)]
    public int[] Bar {get;set;}
}
```

since this will have known endianness, handle buffering, and will use variable-length encoding to help reduce bloat if most of the numbers aren't enormous.

Comment: (just tested with the sample data; 6 bytes via protobuf instead of 20 - of course it helps that the numbers I'm using are all small)