# Loading from file System.IO Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have little problem with loading from binary file

```
        FileStream yay = new FileStream(@"c:\\StatsSave\save.bin", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader yay01 = new BinaryReader(yay);


        label02.Text = yay01.ReadString();
        label01.Text = yay01.ReadString();
        listBox.Items.Add(yay01.ReadString());

        yay.Close();
        yay01.Close();
```

this is my loading I guess problem is somewhere in ListBox
if you want here is saving

```
        FileStream yay = new FileStream(@"c:\\StatsSave\save.bin", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter yay01 = new BinaryWriter(yay);

        string win = Convert.ToString(label02.Text);
        string lose = Convert.ToString(label01.Text);
        foreach(string game in listBox.Items)
        {
            yay01.Write(game);
        }
        yay01.Write(win);
        yay01.Write(lose);

        yay.Close();
        yay01.Close();
```

I am trying solve this by two hours and now I have to please for yours answers. 
Thanks and sorry for my english it isn't my native language and I am out of powers

Comment: Can you provide the exception? and you're gonna want to rename all of your variables. It's making it pretty damn hard to read. "fileStream" instead of "yay"

Comment: Side note: What is the point of calling `Convert.ToString` on `string`?

Comment: "I have little problem with loading from binary file" is about as useful for getting help as going to the doctor and saying "I don't feel well" and nothing more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744392/read-an-array-of-32bit-ints-from-a-binary-format-file shows reading/writing arrays. Possibly this is exactly what you have problem with, but it is hard to say from your post.

Comment: Using [`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx). and [`System.IO.File.WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx) will make it really easy for you to load all items from a file and save all items to a file.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you should close dependent things in reverse order. Because you instantiated BinaryWriter second, you should close it first before closing FileStream, i.e., `yay01.Close();` first then `yay.Close();` second.

Comment: my eyes hurt reading this code.. what kind of variable naming convention are you following..? is that considered `Yami` case..? try reading the [MSDN BinaryWriter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)

Comment: I didn't know how to name that so accordingly it seems but I sort through this code

Answer (score 0):

ListBox.Items is of type ObjectCollection, so you'll want to use

```
foreach(object game in listBox.Items)
        {
            yay01.Write(game.ToString());
        }
```

Also, be sure c:\StatsSave\save.bin exists

Comment: Thanks but it's kinda.. eh..it's not what I expect for [link](http://imgur.com/a/zYHo5)

Comment: I'm sorry my example didn't help you, but you are being extremely vague about the result you are expecting to achieve.

Comment: My friend told me to compare saving with loading that is why I posted only what I posted but he doesn't want to tell me how to solve that. I don't know if I am helping you with your solve but that is all what I can tell about this

Comment: This article will give you a place to start. There are many different tools you can use in order to manage your I/O streams. But I highly recommend starting with simple console applications until you get the hang of working with memory streams...
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_file_io.htm